# Lightning Web Components lightning-datatable detect "select all" checkbox

Tags: lightning-web-components, datatable, pagination, lightning-datatable

When using the `lightning-datatable` component, by default each row has a checkbox beside it (unless so explictely specify `hideCheckboxColumn` to `false`). So when a row is selected the `onrowselection` event is fired for that row.

I was wondering if there's a way to detect when the checkbox at the header is selected (the one that selects all rows). I need to detect this since I want to implement a paginator and when the checkbox in the header is checked I want to also check rows in the other pages.

Any viable way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. The datatable connectCallback function registers handlers for selectAll and deSelectAll

I needed for modify the working of selectAll and Deselectall with respect to disabled rows. So i created a new LWC extending the lighting data table and overrode the connectedCallback function and the handler method too.

This code is from the datatable.js - the js file for the base lighting datable component.

```
connectedCallback() {
        const {
            handleResizeColumn,
            handleUpdateColumnSort,
            handleCellFocusByClick,
            handleFalseCellBlur
        } = this;
        this.template.addEventListener('selectallrows', handleSelectAllRows.bind(this));
        this.template.addEventListener('deselectallrows', handleDeselectAllRows.bind(this));this.template.addEventListener('selectrow', handleSelectRow.bind(this));
    this.template.addEventListener('deselectrow', handleDeselectRow.bind(this));
    this.addEventListener('rowselection', handleRowSelectionChange.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `rowselection` event is not being fired on check all - then currently there aren't any (public) custom events that are emitted. [Per the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) we only have:

- cancel
- resize
- rowselection
- save
- sort

Theoretically - the workaround would be to overlay a div and capture a click event with a delay (every time) and check:

```js
const selected = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').getSelectedRows()
```

And do some logic based on your known `rows.length` vs that `selected.length`;

Answer (score 0):

if you implemented a paginator in lightning-datatable use  key-field="AnyUniqueId" attribute to avoid the rows checked in other pages.